# org-capture datetree inside current buffer not working

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

i want to capture into a datetree inside the current buffer.
Below is my snippet.
But unfortunately it doesn't work.
Always an error:
org-capture-expand-file: Invalid file location: nil

I use emacs 28 with Org 9.4 on Linux Fedora34.

```
("a" "Datetree in act. Buffer"
       entry (file+olp+datetree (buffer-file-name))
       "* TODO %?\nSCHEDULED: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t \"+0d\"))\n%a\nAdded: %U"
   :empty-lines 1
       :tree-type week)
```

Does anybody know, how to fix it?
The function (buffer-file-name) returns the correct filename with path, exactly like i wrote it as string.

Regards
Poul

Comment: You want to pass the function itself, not the result of its evaluation. Try `(file+olp+datetree buffer-file-name)`.

Comment: Wonderful! Works.  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but i do not understand how to accept your answer.

Comment: I made it a comment, not an answer, because it was short and I didn't have to think much about  *how* to make it into an answer :-) So, yes,you can't accept it, but that's OK: don't worry about it. If I find some time, I'll come back and make it into a proper answer. Glad it worked!